# In Terminal, 'Meta+L' is somehow shortcut for 'ls'. How to disable it?

Tags: terminal

In macOS' Terminal, the <kbd>Meta</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> (or <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> if you enabled "Use Option as Meta key" in settings) is somehow a shortcut for `ls`.

How do I disable it? I want to use shell default <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for converting to lowercase. The opposite shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> (convert to uppercase) works as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's part of zsh keybindings. You can see them with typing `bindkey` in Terminal. By default it says:

```
"^[l" "ls^J"
```

You can change this to "downcase" with

```
bindkey "^[l" down-case-word
```

If you are using oh-my-zsh it's set in

```
~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/key-bindings.zsh
```

with `bindkey -s '\el' 'ls\n' # [Esc-l] - run command: ls`

Comment: thank you, it`s exactly what i needed!